# How to change Vuforia AR camera focus mode?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using **Vuforia 6.2 AR SDK** for in Unity. But while I test the application in Android phone the camera seems like **blurry**. I searched in Vuforia's developer website and found some camera focus mode but I can't implement because that guideline was for older Vuforia SDK, I can't find the script they mentioned in their website. Here is their code sample but it's not working. I created different script and run this line on Start() function, but still not working.

```
CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(
        CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
```

Comment: The package comes with examples that includes a menu (do double tap on your phone to show it) in which you can toggle autofocus. If it doesn't work in that way, probably the problem is your device.

Comment: Make sure you include this at the top of your script:

using Vuforia;

Comment: Where is to use this code? In wich file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
void Start () 
{
    VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
    VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnPaused);
}
  
private void OnVuforiaStarted()
{
    CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(
        CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
}
  
private void OnPaused(bool paused)
{
    if (!paused) // resumed
    {
        // Set again autofocus mode when app is resumed
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(
            CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, you are correct! But you need to replace 'VuforiaBehaviour' with 'VuforiaARController'.
Such as :

VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
  VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnPaused);

Comment: It's very frustrating that they updated the SDK but didn't updated the documentation yet! 
I modified first 2 lines, now it's working for me! 

Do edit your code and I will take it as answer. Thank you

Comment: @Turzo Thanks I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

This code is the right code.

```
bool cameramode = false;
public void OnCameraChangeMode()
{
    Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection currentDir = Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraDirection();
    if (!cameramode) {
        RestartCamera(Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
        camBtnTxt.text = "Back Camera";
    } else {
        RestartCamera(Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
        camBtnTxt.text = "Front Camera";
    }
}

private void RestartCamera(Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection newDir)
{
    Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
    Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();
    Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Init(newDir);
    Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Start();
}
```

Comment: Hi, the 1st answer provided by @Subham was the right thing I was searching about. Thanks for your answer! :)