# Camera not focusing while using vuforia SDK to create AR app in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

My camera is not focusing on my image target. The camera is blurred. My normal camera app functions properly. In my AR app the camera is not focusing.

Comment: When did this occur? Is this since you added vuforia, or more recently? Did you edit or add any particular code before this happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Vuforia AR camera focus mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607773/how-to-change-vuforia-ar-camera-focus-mode)